# Azure - Multiple ResourceGroup based cost dashboard not working

Tags: azure, cost-management, azure-dashboard, azure-monitor-workbooks

Can someone confirm if Multiple resource group based cost dashboard is possible in Azure?
Ex:

| RG-Name | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| DEV-APP01 | - 100 |
| UAT-APP01 | - 300 |
| PRD-APP01 | - 500 |

We have a RGs created based on applications and sending the cost using Runbook based on Tag or RG. But instead of sending the cost manually, we planned to create a dashboard for them so that they can view it on Azure dashboard. Every App owner has a contributor rights on their RG and they can view all the resources deployed including costs. RG details are Ex,

DEV-APP01, UAT-APP01, PRD-APP01 - AppOwner-1
DEV-APP02, UAT-APP02, PRD-APP02 - AppOwner-2
DEV-APP03, UAT-APP03, PRD-APP03 - AppOwner-3

We have used Cost Management feature to create the dashboard for AppOwners and created the same in by selecting multiple RG and pin the same in Azure dashboard. But the AppOwner is not able to see the cost, As the cost management scope is based on subscriptions, they can't see the cost associated for all of their RGs. Is there anyway where we can consolidate all the resource group and display it in Azure dashboard?

I have used Workbook & API combination targetting to Subscription as well as specific RG but multiple RG cost display is not working.

API for subscription - /subscriptions/{Subscription:Id}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query? - Getting not authorized for AppOwner, i think due to the RG only permission

API for RG- /subscriptions/{Subscription:Id}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query? - Able to pull only one RG and if AppOwner select multiple RG, results are not populated.

Comment: which part of it isn't working?  is it the cost management query not returning what you expect?  can you show a more concrete example of exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Can we use multiple resource groups in the above said API?

Comment: it doesn't look like it?  sometimes the owners of hte api document ways to use their REST API against a subscription, and then pass extra filters in the body or odata filter style in the url? but i don't see anything obvious.  you might have to do it one by one by selecting a RG in the param and seeing the results?  then switching to anothhher?